# C# listening to serial port and proceed as needed , after page loaded on client side

Tags: c#, asp.net, serial-port

I'm developing an  C#/Asp.net application that comunicates with a device that uses serial ports.

First, i have a button that does the following:

```
Response.Redirect("Zxx.aspx?ValtoSibs=" + Strvals);
```

That basically redirects me to the page where i open my serial port, write into int and then want to read any input i get from the device for example, if i click on a key on the device i want to read it in the application and proceed as i want to.

Here is the code that's running on **Zxx.aspx**

```
 protected void Page_LoadComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)

        {
            string ValtoSibs = Request.QueryString["ValtoSibs"];
            SIBS.SIBS ComTPA = new SIBS.SIBS();
            ComTPA.IniciaTPA();
            ComTPA.SendPaymentCmd(Int32.Parse(ValtoSibs));




                if (ComTPA.ComTPA.ReadExisting().Contains("M001909"))

                {
                    ComTPA.ComTPA.DiscardInBuffer();
                    ComTPA.ComTPA.DiscardOutBuffer();
                    ComTPA.CloseTPA();
                    Response.Redirect("Erro.aspx");

                }
        }
```

In the block above, i can't know if any button is pressed on the device , because i need a while loop encapsulating the block:

```
  if (ComTPA.ComTPA.ReadExisting().Contains("M001909"))

                {
                    ComTPA.ComTPA.DiscardInBuffer();
                    ComTPA.ComTPA.DiscardOutBuffer();
                    ComTPA.CloseTPA();
                    Response.Redirect("Erro.aspx");

                }
```

The problem is , when i try to put a while cycle , the page doesn't load zxx.aspx doesn't load, it locks on an infinite loop BUT when i press any key on the device, for example the one that sends the **M001909 string** , it acts as needed, closes the port and redirects the page.

My main problem is, i need to be in **Zxx.aspx** page , already fully loaded on client side and then have the while cycle working behind so that i can listen to the commands sent on the device.

Comment: Okay, one question for you; what must happen if a key on the device is pressed?

Comment: In this moment i'm only testing one key, the key sends to the buffer a string that contains the "M001909" value , if it contains it should close the port and redirect to the Erro.aspx page. This works if i adda while cycle but doesn't load the Zxx.aspx page ( infinite loading until while cycle is done)

Comment: So what about using a post method instead of using a while to redirect ? Or maybe an ajax call or a WebSocket ?

Comment: I think i'm being misunderstood, my first redirect it's fine , the problem is i need to constantly listen to any input send by the serial device to the program and if i try to achieve that using a while cycle , the page on it should have redirected to doesn't load until the while cycle ends. it's like i need some sort of away to run the while cycle after the page is rendered or another way to listen to the port. Very thanks for all of the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution,

I created a new DataReceived Handler and inside it called a function that does the following and take as parameter ReadExisting ():

```
if (ComTPA.ComTPA.ReadExisting().Contains("M001909"))

                {
                    ComTPA.ComTPA.DiscardInBuffer();
                    ComTPA.ComTPA.DiscardOutBuffer();
                    ComTPA.CloseTPA();
                    Response.Redirect("Erro.aspx");

                }
```